# ssms cannot connect to default sql server instance without specifying port number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, networking, ssms

I have multiple SQL Server 2005 instances on a box. From SSMS on my desktop I can connect to that box's named instances with no problem. After some recent network configuration changes, when I want to connect to the default instance from SSMS on my desktop, I have to specify the port number. Before the network changes, I did *not* have to specify the port number of the default instance.

If I remote to any other box (including the one in question), and use *that* box's SSMS to connect to that default instance, success. From my desktop, and only from my desktop, I have to specify the port number.

Is it a SQL Server configuration that I've missed? Is it possible something in my PC's configuration is getting in the way? Where would I look, or what could I pass on to the network folks to help them resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What port number do you type when it works?

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to my_server_name.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10061)

Comment: I should also specify that applications are still able to connect to all the instances on this box, default and named alike, as expected, without having to add the port number.

Comment: Is the SQL server browser service running on the host? and what exactly is "some recent network config. changes"

Comment: The browser service is running; that is why I'm able to connect to the named instances without having to specify their ports. 

I wish I knew what the network changes were. That information is not available to me.

Comment: update: Resolved. I regret not knowing the details, but the issue was resolved after some network configuration changes, to which I was not privy. I made no changes to rectify the issue, and I know there were no restarts/reboots for this instance/box, therefore I conclude that it was some network setting.

Answer (score 4):

Port 1434 is blocked somewhere along the line, which is used to resolve instance name to port number.

If you specifiy a port number, instance name is ignored...

[SQL Server Browser service listens on port 1434](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx)

> Upon startup, **SQL Server Browser
>   starts and claims UDP port 1434**. SQL
>   Server Browser reads the registry,
>   identifies all instances of SQL Server
>   on the computer, and notes the ports
>   and named pipes that they use. When a
>   server has two or more network cards,
>   SQL Server Browser returns the first
>   enabled port it encounters for SQL
>   Server. SQL Server Browser support [sic]
>   ipv6 and ipv4.
>
> When SQL Server clients request SQL
>   Server resources, **the client network
>   library sends a UDP message to the
>   server using port 1434. SQL Server
>   Browser responds** with the TCP/IP port
>   or named pipe of the requested
>   instance. The network library on the
>   client application then completes the
>   connection by sending a request to the
>   server using the port or named pipe of
>   the desired instance.

Edit, after comment:

What is the local client setting default? It should be 1433 of course, but if not then just servername will not work.

Launch "SQL Server Configuration Manager".. "SQL native client configuration".. "client protocols".. double click tcp/ip, the default port used by your local PC is there.

Comment: @gbn: the default instance is assigned to 1433 during installation (and that is how it remains in this case); further, even if SQLBrowser is malfunctioning, the default instance should still be accessible without having to specify the port number; your answer addresses the named instances, with which I have no issues

Comment: @Oliver: sorry, I read it wrong way around. What is your client setting default? It should be 1433 of course, but if not then just servername will not work. SQL Server config mananger.. SQL native client config.. client protocols..double click tcp/ip

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen on Windows 2008/7/Vista boxes that have the firewall turned on.  Using the named instance does not work but specifying the port does.  The fix for me was to set up a firewall rules for SSMS and DTExec in order to allow for normal connections.  The script to do so is below but you may have to change the patch to SSMS and DTExec.

```
rem SSMS
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SQL-SSMS dir=in action=allow program="D:\Apps\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" enable=yes profile=domain
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SQL-SSMS dir=out action=allow program="D:\Apps\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" enable=yes profile=domain

rem DTExec
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SQL-DTExec dir=in action=allow program="D:\Apps\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" enable=yes profile=domain
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SQL-DTExec dir=out action=allow program="D:\Apps\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" enable=yes profile=domain

rem DTExec32
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SQL-DTExec32 dir=in action=allow program="D:\Apps\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" enable=yes profile=domain
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SQL-DTExec32 dir=out action=allow program="D:\Apps\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" enable=yes profile=domain
```